# My openshift application PDO query didn't work

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, openshift

I am try to connect phpmyadmin database using my php script in openshift

but the result is a empty page.

then, I find the question is the query didn't work

but I don't know why

There is my original code

```
try{
        $dsn = 'mysql:dbname=exampleDataBase;host=127.**.***.***;port=*****';
        $dbh = new PDO($dsn, "account", "password");
        $sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM test1');
        $fin = $sth->execute();
        while($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            print_r($row);
        }
    } catch (PDOException $e){
        echo "Sytan error" . $e -> getMessage();
    }
    $dbh = null;
```

and the result is a empty page, so I modify my code

There is my modify code

```
try{
        $dsn = 'mysql:dbname=exampleDataBase;host=127.**.***.***;port=*****';
        $dbh = new PDO($dsn, "account", "password");
        $sth = $dbh->prepare('jngfcjfgcnmgcm,,hmnxf');
        $fin = $sth->execute();
        while($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            print_r($row);
        }
    } catch (PDOException $e){
        echo "Sytan error" . $e -> getMessage();
    }
    $dbh = null;
```

I input the wrong query sytanx(jngfcjfgcnmgcm,,hmnxf), but it didn't return error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your script see your errors

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('html_errors', 1);
```

and change your query code to this, see notes

```
  try{
    //port=***** is only need where its different from the default
    $dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=exampleDataBase';
    $options = array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, "account", "password", $options);
    $sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM test1');
    // execute $sth
    $sth->execute();
    //Change fetch to fetchAll
    while($row = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        print_r($row);
    }
} catch (PDOException $e){
    echo "Sytan error" . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer
But it didn't work
I have use 
 `error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ini_set('display_errors', 1);`
to show php error

Comment: It still a empty page

Comment: Very thank you  It work!!!!     Sytan errorSQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '��工' at line 1         I thank is the Encoding question     Because I use chinese of the database

Answer (score 0):

You modified your code to a wrong statement to see the error message?
You have your PHP errors turned off, when doing a statement like:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare('jngfcjfgcnmgcm,,hmnxf');
```

You would receive an error like:

> **Sytan error**SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You
>   have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to
>   your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
>   'jngfcjfgcnmgcm,,hmnxf' at line 1

What do you exactly want? The exception is not showing?

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
I want the data in mysql
It realy didn't have any exception...